# How to replace autofill range based on data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me replace the autofill range code to one that would account for variances in the table RPdata columns. Can see that for A, range is currently set as A2:A520, and I tried building a automatic range to account for any variances but it doesn't work (Compile error).

```
   Sheets("Calc Data").Select

        Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=CONCATENATE(RPdata[@[Parish Code]]&"", ""&RPdata[@Parish])"
        Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A520"), Type:=xlFillDefaul

        Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RPdata[@[Building ID 1]]"
        Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("RPdata[@[Building ID1]]" & Rows.Count).End(1xUp).Row)
```

Comment: Is `xlFillDefaul` just a typo here? Also, what line throws what error?

Comment: Not sure, it seems to be working with that line. 
The error is highlighting this code
`Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("RPdata[@[Building ID1]]" & Rows.Count).End(1xUp).Row` For compile and syntax errors

Comment: `End(1xUp)` has a **one** not an **el** and it's reversed like `End(xlup)`. you want ex-el-up.

Comment: Are you trying to populate a blank column? The method you are using locates the last populated row in a column when you spell it correctly. Shouldn't you pick a column that already has data in it to locate the last destination row?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Sorry Jeeped. I would like for my range to do the formula specified for the range that exists in the RPdata table. So if the table has more rows, the formula in columns A, B etc all use the same range rather than me manually changing the range each time there are changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the row count of the table to shape the destination range.

```
dim rws as long

with workSheets("Calc Data")

    rws = .listobjects("RPdata").databodyrange.rows.count

    .cells(2, "A").resize(rws, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE(RPdata[@[Parish Code]]&"", ""&RPdata[@Parish])"
    .cells(2, "B").resize(rws, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RPdata[@[Building ID 1]]"

end with
```